# Why does HMS Delete token crash?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Trying to build a react-native Huawei app, but I have a problem with

`HmsInstanceId.getInstance(ActivityUtils.getRealActivity(getCurrentActivity(), getContext())) .deleteToken(appId, scope);`

function in the @hmscore/react-native-hms-push. Why could that be? I am using versions

- @hmscore/react-native-hms-push: 6.11.0-300
- EMUI: 12.0.1.195

The get and store token functions work without a hitch, but the delete function just crashes the app.

I can't find any smoking gun in the logcat either:

```
2023-12-08 11:50:40.974 24789-18391 ReactNativeJS           com.my.package.dev          I  deleting token
2023-12-08 11:50:40.977 24789-18392 HMSSDK_n                com.my.package.dev          I  secretKeyCache not empty.
2023-12-08 11:50:40.978 24789-18392 HMSSDK_n                com.my.package.dev          I  The local secret is already in separate file mode.
2023-12-08 11:50:40.978  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755127665020, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:40.980 24789-18392 HMSSDK_HMS...ageManager com.my.package.dev          I  Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
2023-12-08 11:50:40.981 24789-18392 AGC_FixedDecrypt        com.my.package.dev          D  init
2023-12-08 11:50:40.982 24789-18392 AGC_Keys                com.my.package.dev          D  build aes key, iterationCount:5000
2023-12-08 11:50:41.024   709-742   libnetd_resolv          netd                                 W  A binder object at 0xb400007373e0e400 is being transacted on, however, this object is in the same process as its proxy. Transacting with this binder is expensive compared to just calling the corresponding functionality in the same process.
2023-12-08 11:50:41.047 24789-18392 AGC_Keys                com.my.package.dev          D  build aes key end
2023-12-08 11:50:41.050 24789-18392 HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer com.my.package.dev          I  Builder->biInitFlag :false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.050 24789-18392 HMSSDK_Util             com.my.package.dev          I  available exist: true
2023-12-08 11:50:41.051 24789-18392 HMSSDK_AvailableUtil    com.my.package.dev          I  asyncCheckHmsUpdateInfo, not need to check
2023-12-08 11:50:41.054 24789-18392 HMSSDK_HMS...ageManager com.my.package.dev          I  Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
2023-12-08 11:50:41.058 24789-18392 SecurityCo...aseKeyUtil com.my.package.dev          I  exportRootKey: sha256
2023-12-08 11:50:41.078  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755227486895, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.081  1133-2776  AwareLog                system_server                        E  CpuHighFgControl: getContentWithOneLine file not exists or canot read!
2023-12-08 11:50:41.086  1173-1287  afehal_test             aptouch_daemon                       E  [1702032641085][T:1702032641.086065]tp_thp_slave_mode_send_cmd 840:cmd = 0x74, write len = 6 read len = 4
2023-12-08 11:50:41.093  1173-1287  afehal_test             aptouch_daemon                       E  vendor_parse_ioctrl_frame:[1702032641093][T:1702032641.093736]vendor_parse_ioctrl_frame 562:afe_status = 0x1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.093  1173-1287  aptouch_daemon          aptouch_daemon                       I  status=0x1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.093  1173-1287  aptouch_daemon          aptouch_daemon                       E  TsaFrame::UpdateStatusIdle[1810] idle in. 300
2023-12-08 11:50:41.152  3158-4893  Booster_Qoe             com.huawei.systemserver              I  AdaBoostPredict rlt,index:8,NisPsSlow:0,NProba:309,rsrp(rssi):-60,rsrq(noise):-60,rtt(chload):200,buffhigh(uldelay):0,buffcomm(rtt):0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.152  3158-4893  Booster_Qoe             com.huawei.systemserver              I  AdaBoostPredict rlt,index:2,NisPsSlow:0,NProba:309,rsrp(rssi):-60,rsrq(noise):-60,rtt(chload):200,buffhigh(uldelay):0,buffcomm(rtt):0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.153  1133-2776  AwareLog                system_server                        E  CpuHighFgControl: getContentWithOneLine file not exists or canot read!
2023-12-08 11:50:41.154  3476-4504  ash_dd                  com.huawei.iaware                    I  com.huawei.filemanager not ctrl in charging, delay to D!
2023-12-08 11:50:41.156  1133-2776  AwareLog                system_server                        E  CpuHighFgControl: getContentWithOneLine file not exists or canot read!
2023-12-08 11:50:41.160  3158-3366  NpdcpAliveManager       com.huawei.systemserver              D  ro.odm.npdcp_alive_cfg_enable is false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  3158-3909  Hicom_Monitor           com.huawei.systemserver              I  handleNetworkQoeReport. foregroundAppTcpRtt: 0, maxRatioChannelId: 2
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  3158-3909  Hicom_Monitor           com.huawei.systemserver              I  handleNetworkQoeReport. qoeString: 10190,4,0,309,1,2,4,0,309,200000,180000,10,10,0,0,0,0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  3158-3909  Hicom_Monitor           com.huawei.systemserver              I  appQoe uid:10190, qoeLevel:4
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  1133-2894  WiFi_PRO_W...ateMachine system_server                        I  APP_SERVICE_QOE_NOTIFY Qoe info 10190,4,0,309,1,2,4,0,309,200000,180000,10,10,0,0,0,0 CID 2 mMasterWifiRssi -60 mMasterCardAmbr 1048576 mSlaveCardAmbr 1048576
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  3158-3909  Hicom_Monitor           com.huawei.systemserver              I  channelQoe ind:2, qoeLevel:4
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  1133-2894  WifiService             system_server                        I  getConnectionInfo, uid =1000, calling by: android, isNeedApproximateLocation = false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  1133-2894  HwWifiServiceFactory    system_server                        V  get AllImpl object = com.android.server.wifi.HwWifiServiceFactoryImpl@c0ec8a9
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  1133-2894  HwWifiProServiceProxy   system_server                        I  ctrlHwWifiNetwork pkgName: WIFIPRO_SERVICE interfaceId: 9
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  1133-2894  WiFi_PRO_W...ateMachine system_server                        I  isWifi2WifiProcess = false, mIsNeedIgnoreQoeUpdate = false, mIsAppInBlacklist = false, mIsAppInBlacklistFullScreen = false, mIsWiFiNoInternet false, screen on = true, full screen = false, isLandscapeMode = false, mNotifyWifiLinkPoorReason = -1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  1133-2894  WiFi_PRO_W...ateMachine system_server                        I  mChannelQoeBadCnt = 0, mAppQoeBadCnt = 0, mNetworkSlowReason = 0, mNetworkSlowChannelBadCnt = 0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  1133-2894  WifiService             system_server                        I  getConnectionInfo, uid =1000, calling by: android, isNeedApproximateLocation = false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.161  1133-2894  HwWifiServiceFactory    system_server                        V  get AllImpl object = com.android.server.wifi.HwWifiServiceFactoryImpl@c0ec8a9
2023-12-08 11:50:41.162  1133-2894  WiFi_PROHu...rRecommend system_server                        E  isRichTrafficUser, invalid slotId=-1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.162  1133-2894  WiFi_PROHu...rRecommend system_server                        E  isEconomicTrafficUser, invalid slotId=-1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.162  1133-2894  WiFi_PROHu...rRecommend system_server                        E  isRichTrafficUser, invalid slotId=-1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.162  1133-2894  WifiService             system_server                        I  getConnectionInfo, uid =1000, calling by: android, isNeedApproximateLocation = false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.162  1133-2894  HwWifiServiceFactory    system_server                        V  get AllImpl object = com.android.server.wifi.HwWifiServiceFactoryImpl@c0ec8a9
2023-12-08 11:50:41.165  3158-4893  Collector               com.huawei.systemserver              I  HandleRawWifiInfo: flag:0, netId:0!
2023-12-08 11:50:41.166  3158-4893  Collector               com.huawei.systemserver              I  HandleRawWifiInfo: flag:0, netId:0!
2023-12-08 11:50:41.178  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755327553405, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.196 24789-18514 HMSSDK_HMS...ageManager com.my.package.dev          I  Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
2023-12-08 11:50:41.196 24789-18514 HMSSDK_HuaweiApi        com.my.package.dev          I  No setInnerHms, hms pkg name is com.huawei.hwid
2023-12-08 11:50:41.197 24789-18514 HMSSDK_HuaweiApi        com.my.package.dev          I  sendRequest
2023-12-08 11:50:41.198 24789-18514 HMSSDK_HMS...ageManager com.my.package.dev          I  Enter getHMSPackageName
2023-12-08 11:50:41.199 24789-18514 HMSSDK_HuaweiApi        com.my.package.dev          I  isConnected:true.
2023-12-08 11:50:41.200 24789-18514 HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient    com.my.package.dev          I  getAdapter:isInner:false, mInnerBinderAdapter:null, mOuterBinderAdapter:com.huawei.hms.adapter.OuterBinderAdapter@5cc2fb4
2023-12-08 11:50:41.200 24789-18514 HMSSDK_RequestManager   com.my.package.dev          I  addToConnectedReqMap
2023-12-08 11:50:41.201 24789-18514 HMSSDK_HmsClient        com.my.package.dev          I  post msg api_name:push.deletetoken, app_id:{app_id}|, pkg_name:com.my.package.dev, sdk_version:61100301, session_id:*, transaction_id:{app_id}etoken{dated_token_id}, kitSdkVersion:61100100, apiLevel:1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.202 24789-18514 HMSSDK_BaseAdapter      com.my.package.dev          I  In constructor, activityWeakReference is java.lang.ref.WeakReference@5e712e0, activity is com.my.package.MainActivity@8b4c8f7
2023-12-08 11:50:41.202  1133-2813  TrafficMonitor          system_server                        I  update:rxPkts:3,txPkts:0,rxBytes:240,txBytes:0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.203  1133-2813  TrafficMonitor          system_server                        I  gettimer:interval=2000
2023-12-08 11:50:41.209 24789-18514 HMSSDK_BaseAdapter      com.my.package.dev          I  in baseRequest + uri is :push.deletetoken, transactionId is : {app_id}etoken{dated_token_id}
2023-12-08 11:50:41.211 24789-18514 HMSSDK_Pen...ResultImpl com.my.package.dev          I  init uri:push.deletetoken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.212 24789-18514 HMSSDK_Pen...ResultImpl com.my.package.dev          I  setResultCallback
2023-12-08 11:50:41.213  3101-8666  AIDLInvoke              com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore AIDLInvoke.java:7] <apirouter>Request, URI: push.deletetoken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.215  3101-8666  PackageUtils            com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore PackageUtils.java:1] uid:10190, packageName:com.my.package.dev
2023-12-08 11:50:41.217  3101-18733 AppScope                com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore AppScope.java:6] permission not exist:{app_id}/com.huawei.hms.appservice.cps
2023-12-08 11:50:41.218  3101-18733 fwkit_ApiRuleEngine     com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit ApiRuleEngine.java:222] bgRules, apiName: push.deletetoken appId: {app_id} permission: null business:Default
2023-12-08 11:50:41.219  3101-18733 fwkit_coresm            com.huawei.hwid.core                 W  [fwkit CoreServiceManager.java:77] Get vr_system Service !but its binder is null!
2023-12-08 11:50:41.219  3101-18733 HwVrServiceManagerImpl  com.huawei.hwid.core                 E  client service is not alive.
2023-12-08 11:50:41.219  3101-18733 fwkit_sdk_apiRouter     com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  newApiName is push.deletetoken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.220  3101-18733 RuleEngineService       com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore RuleEngineService.java:8] AIDLRequest modify route info,oldApiName:push.deletetoken, newApiName:push.deletetoken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.220  3101-18733 AIDLInvoke              com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore AIDLInvoke.java:7] push.deletetoken->push.deletetoken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.220  3101-18733 AIDLInvoke              com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore AIDLInvoke.java:4] push apiLvl:-1,1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.220  3101-18733 fwkit_sdk_fd            com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  createRequestFromMessageCenter uri: push.deletetoken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.221  3101-18733 fwkit_kims...atcher_fdi com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit DispatcherImpl.java:112] MessageCenter uri: push.deletetoken appId: {app_id} hostAppId: {app_id} apiLevel: 1 runtime api level: 28
2023-12-08 11:50:41.222  3101-18733 fwkit_kit_breaker       com.huawei.hwid.core                 W  [fwkit KitBreaker.java:343] infos invalid
2023-12-08 11:50:41.223  3101-18733 fwkit_kims...estFactory com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit RequestFactory.java:47] No uri matched, choose proxy request as default.
2023-12-08 11:50:41.224  3101-18733 KitMessageCenter        com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore KitMessageCenter.java:14] Find makeRequest uri:push.deletetoken cost time: 3ms
2023-12-08 11:50:41.224  3101-18733 AIDLInvoke              com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore AIDLInvoke.java:8] Request, URI: push.deletetoken, clientId: {appId: {app_id}, hostAppID: {app_id}, packageName: com.my.package.dev, sdkVersion: 61100301, uid: 10190, transactionId: {app_id}etoken{dated_token_id}, apiLevel: 1, uri: push.deletetoken, kitSdkVersion: 61100100}
2023-12-08 11:50:41.226  3101-5058  fwkit_presetUtil        com.huawei.hwid.core                 E  getSystemApp flag error for com.google.android.gms:NameNotFoundException
2023-12-08 11:50:41.227  3101-5058  FormalHASDK             com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  HAImpl==> onEvent. tag:HmsProfiler, type:0, eventId:HMS_API_CALLED
2023-12-08 11:50:41.228  3101-18733 fwkit_kims              com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit KIMSServiceController.java:725] getKitInfo S: :push
2023-12-08 11:50:41.229  3101-18733 fwkit_kams_stubmanager  com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit StubManagerService.java:449] getSPNByComponent:com.huawei.hms.push, com.huawei.hms.push, false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.230  3101-18733 fwkit_kams_scheduler    com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit ProcessScheduler.java:411] RC:com.huawei.hwid.core
2023-12-08 11:50:41.230  3101-18733 fwkit_kams              com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit KAMSServiceController.java:1231] Assign com.huawei.hwid.core for push/com.huawei.hms.push/com.huawei.hms.push cost 6ms
2023-12-08 11:50:41.231  3101-18733 fwkit_kams_stubmanager  com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit StubManagerService.java:449] getSPNByComponent:com.huawei.hms.push, com.huawei.hms.push, false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.232  3101-18733 fwkit_kams_scheduler    com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit ProcessScheduler.java:411] RC:com.huawei.hwid.core
2023-12-08 11:50:41.232  3101-18733 fwkit_msg_request_proxy com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit AIDLRequestLocalProxy.java:171] request:ae873c25-d56e-459d-8d89-133f4814c147/push.deletetoken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.237  3101-18735 fwkit_msg_invoke_remote com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit AIDLInvokeRemote.java:131] execute requestId:ae873c25-d56e-459d-8d89-133f4814c147 uri:push.deletetoken transactionId:{app_id}etoken{dated_token_id}
2023-12-08 11:50:41.238  3101-18735 fwkit_msg_fr            com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit FinderRemote.java:93] findRequest uri: push.deletetoken apiLevel: 1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.239  3101-18735 fwkit_kac_kitloader     com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit KitLoaderManager.java:210] kit loaded push_61200300 already exits, cost :1 ms
2023-12-08 11:50:41.241  3101-18735 fwkit_msg_aidl_request  com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit AIDLRequest.java:125] execute:{app_id}etoken{dated_token_id}
2023-12-08 11:50:41.242  3101-18521 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:163] countryCode by ro.hw.country is: eu
2023-12-08 11:50:41.242  3101-18521 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:196] countryCode by SimCountryIso is: 
2023-12-08 11:50:41.243  3101-18521 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:236] countryCode by system's region setting is: CZ
2023-12-08 11:50:41.243  3101-18521 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:214] EMUI 9.0 upper System, get countryCode form Locale.getDefault().getCountry()
2023-12-08 11:50:41.243  3101-18521 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:126] get issue_country code from LOCALE_INFO
2023-12-08 11:50:41.244  3101-18735 ScopeManager            com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore ScopeManager.java:1] checkCF {app_id}/com.my.package.dev
2023-12-08 11:50:41.244  3101-18735 HC_PackageUtils         com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore PackageUtils.java:6] com.my.package.dev is OHOS app: false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.245  3101-18736 fwkit_db_S...ngsManager com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit SettingsManager.java:154] The value get from cache.Key is hw_app_analytics_state, value is 0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.245  3101-18735 fwkit_scope_mgr         com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit ScopeManager.java:157] checkCertFingerprint result: 0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.246  3101-18736 fwkit_HmsProfiler       com.huawei.hwid.core                 W  [fwkit HmsProfiler.java:856] deny upload, user not allowed to upload.
2023-12-08 11:50:41.246  3101-18735 fwkit_msg_aidl_request  com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit AIDLRequest.java:219] permission: com.huawei.android.hms.push.manageToken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.250  3101-18735 fwkit_scope_mgr         com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit ScopeManager.java:203] checkPermission result: 0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.251  3101-18735 HMSPushLog61200300      com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [PushKit DeleteTokenRequest.java:174] enter delete token, req:DeleteTokenReq{ pkgName: com.my.package.dev}
2023-12-08 11:50:41.252  3101-18735 HMSPushLog61200300      com.huawei.hwid.core                 D  [PushKit MultiUserUtil.java:82] get CurUserId:0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.252  3101-18735 HMSPushLog61200300      com.huawei.hwid.core                 D  [PushKit CommFun.java:294] existFrameworkPush:1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.252  3101-18735 HMSPushLog61200300      com.huawei.hwid.core                 D  [PushKit CommFun.java:294] existFrameworkPush:1
2023-12-08 11:50:41.253  3101-18735 HMSPushLog61200300      com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [PushKit PendingResultImpl.java:158] await
2023-12-08 11:50:41.254  3101-18735 HMSPushLog61200300      com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [PushKit PendingResultImpl.java:233] awaitOnAnyThread timeout:10 unit:SECONDS
2023-12-08 11:50:41.259  3101-18522 fwkit_kims              com.huawei.hwid.core                 W  [fwkit KIMSServiceController.java:1141] Can't find the specific package.
2023-12-08 11:50:41.264  4756-18523 PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [IO-pool-thread-681-2186]Request, URI: pushcore.deletetoken, clientId: {packageName: com.huawei.hms.push, sdkVersion: 10000000, originPackageName: com.my.package.dev, originAppId: {app_id}, originHostAppId: {app_id}, originSdkVersion: 61100301}
2023-12-08 11:50:41.264  4756-18523 PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [IO-pool-thread-681-2186]DeleteTokenRequest : com.huawei.android.pushagent.core.support.entity.DeleteTokenReq{ pkgName: com.my.package.dev,subjectId:null}
2023-12-08 11:50:41.278  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755427498926, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.289  4756-18523 PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [IO-pool-thread-681-2186]remove old backup token from db
2023-12-08 11:50:41.298  1133-2315  PowerManagerService     system_server                        I  handleSandman: wakefulness: 1,startDreaming: false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.299  4756-18523 PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [IO-pool-thread-681-2186]Response, uri: pushcore.deletetoken, statusCode: 0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.300  3101-8666  HMSPushLog61200300      com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [PushKit PendingResultImpl.java:330] setResult:0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.300  3101-18735 fwkit_msg_aidl_request  com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit AIDLRequest.java:144] onRequest push.deletetoken/{app_id}etoken{dated_token_id} cost 49ms
2023-12-08 11:50:41.301  3101-17936 fwkit_msg_request_proxy com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit AIDLRequestLocalProxy.java:248] AidlCallback:ae873c25-d56e-459d-8d89-133f4814c147/push.deletetoken
2023-12-08 11:50:41.301  3101-17936 fwkit_msg_arw           com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit AIDLResponseWrapper.java:61] callJson start
2023-12-08 11:50:41.302  3101-17936 fwkit_msg_arw           com.huawei.hwid.core                 E  [fwkit AIDLResponseWrapper.java:65] intent is null
2023-12-08 11:50:41.303  3101-18169 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:163] countryCode by ro.hw.country is: eu
2023-12-08 11:50:41.303  3101-18169 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:196] countryCode by SimCountryIso is: 
2023-12-08 11:50:41.303  3101-18169 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:236] countryCode by system's region setting is: CZ
2023-12-08 11:50:41.304  3101-18169 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:214] EMUI 9.0 upper System, get countryCode form Locale.getDefault().getCountry()
2023-12-08 11:50:41.304  3101-18169 fwkit_CountryCodeBean   com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit CountryCodeBean.java:126] get issue_country code from LOCALE_INFO
2023-12-08 11:50:41.305  3101-17936 fwkit_db_S...ngsManager com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit SettingsManager.java:154] The value get from cache.Key is hw_app_analytics_state, value is 0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.305  3101-17936 fwkit_HmsProfiler       com.huawei.hwid.core                 W  [fwkit HmsProfiler.java:856] deny upload, user not allowed to upload.
2023-12-08 11:50:41.306  3101-17936 AIDLResponseImpl        com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [HMSCore AIDLResponseImpl.java:10] Response, uri: push.deletetoken, statusCode: 0, errorCode: 0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.306  4756-4887  PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [AsyncSeqTask-194]get com.huawei.hwid version success , versionCode = 61202302
2023-12-08 11:50:41.306  4756-4887  PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [AsyncSeqTask-194]get com.huawei.android.pushagent version success , versionCode = 110105310
2023-12-08 11:50:41.307  3101-18520 fwkit_db_S...ngsManager com.huawei.hwid.core                 I  [fwkit SettingsManager.java:154] The value get from cache.Key is hw_app_analytics_state, value is 0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.308  3101-18520 fwkit_HmsProfiler       com.huawei.hwid.core                 W  [fwkit HmsProfiler.java:856] deny upload, user not allowed to upload.
2023-12-08 11:50:41.308  4756-4887  PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [AsyncSeqTask-194]execute url is: https://token-dre.push.dbankcloud.com/rest/hwpush/v1/cancel
2023-12-08 11:50:41.314 24789-18272 HMSSDK_Pen...ResultImpl com.my.package.dev          I  setResult:0
2023-12-08 11:50:41.363  4756-4887  PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [AsyncSeqTask-194]close connection
2023-12-08 11:50:41.368  4756-4887  PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [AsyncSeqTask-194]the TokenCancelReq is :{pkgName:com.my.package.dev,subjectId:null,deleteReason:1,ChanMode is: 3,DeviceIdType is: 9,phoneType is: 6}
2023-12-08 11:50:41.379  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755527485749, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.393  3246-7575  HwNaturalBase           com.huawei.HwOPServer                I  [Timer-1]: MultiUserManagerService:  getNotActiveUser start
2023-12-08 11:50:41.400  4756-4887  PushLog110105309        com...android.pushagent.PushService  I  [AsyncSeqTask-194]delete com.my.package.dev user 0 subjectId  messsages
2023-12-08 11:50:41.417  3476-4504  PG_ash                  com.huawei.iaware                    I  has widget app: com.huawei.android.totemweather
2023-12-08 11:50:41.410  3476-3476  com.huawei.iaware       com.huawei.iaware                    W  type=1400 audit(0.0:61830): avc: granted { getattr } for pid=3476 comm=616374696F6E732068616E646C6572 path="/data/system/users/0/appwidgets.xml" dev="sda38" ino=9600 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=file
2023-12-08 11:50:41.417  3476-4504  PG_ash                  com.huawei.iaware                    I  Application com.huawei.android.totemweather, oversea just update widget, delay to H!
2023-12-08 11:50:41.481  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755627682572, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.580  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755727535437, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.679  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755827411166, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.780  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590755927594134, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.880  1489-16734 sensors-hal             ven....hardware.sensors@2.1-service  I  handle_sns_std_sensor_event:65, ambient_light_event: ts=590756027498562, lux = 160, raw_adc=1150
2023-12-08 11:50:41.303  1133-2315  chatty                  system_server                        I  uid=1000(system) PowerManagerSer identical 2 lines
2023-12-08 11:50:41.402  1133-2315  PowerManagerService     system_server                        I  handleSandman: wakefulness: 1,startDreaming: false
2023-12-08 11:50:41.902  1133-2117  ActivityManager         system_server                        I  App 10043/com.android.statementservice targets O+, restricted
2023-12-08 11:50:41.902  1133-2117  ActivityManager         system_server                        W  Stopping service due to app idle: u0a43 -1m9s740ms com.android.statementservice/.DirectStatementService
```

So any idea what am I missing?